# TinyFPGA A Series Board programmer compatibility

Tags: fpga, programmer, lattice

Since the TinyFPGA programmer writes configurations to the Flash memory of the FPGA chip, can I use that programmer for A series boards on any LCMXO2 chip? Or can I at least use it for the same chip with a different package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read, theoretically, yes. I see nothing in the wiring hardware specific to the chip. It's just a JTAG bridge direct wired to the FPGA where everything specific is handled on the PC side, so whatever FPGA the PC software supports.

[image]